# Ubuntu Server 16LTS with Wordpress & Windows Filesystem

Tags: 16.04, server, wordpress

This might be a post loaded with questions, So i'f I'm asking too much, please point me in an alternative direction for advice.

The Setup;
Custom built server (2x 8core Xeons, 48GB RAM, 1000w PSU, 5x 4TB WD SE HDD's in raid 10 (with hotspare)), Running Windows server 2016, with a Hyper-V instance of Ubuntu Server 16 LTS
So far Ubuntu is successfully installed on a Gen2 Hyper V instance with a dedicated switch, completely vanilla at this point.

Scope:
Run a Private Virtual Server at home (Dedicated to one website). Teh website is heavily downloads involved of BMS data. Current website on a shared host has 3000 registered users and about 340GB of download data.

Problem (& how to?):
I will be migrating my shared host website onto a private virtual server at home, hosting off my Gigabit Fiber connection.
The WordPress website will be running in Ubuntu obviously, but i'd much rather prefer to have all my downloads for the site in a Windows format managed directory (*NTFS) structure and be able to link the downloads from WP to that local folder.
This is mostly owing to having over 5,000 individual downloads and about 300 packs of those same downloads.

Considering the above, is there a valid approach for me here?

Comment: Short answer is no, ntfs is a poor choice for this. First linux can not always fix ntfs if the file system needs repair and second ntfs does not fully support linux permissions. Links are a security risk for apache

Comment: Thanks for your advice Panther - In your opinion, are there any utilities for managing a vast array of files hosted on my website?